# summarize across -- is it order dependent?

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize, across

I came across something weird with `dplyr` and `across`, or at least something I do not understand.

If we use the across function to compute the `mean` and `standard error of the mean` across multiple columns, I am tempted to use the following command:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(gear) %>% select(mpg,cyl) %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), ~mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE), .names = "{col}"),
            across(everything(), ~sd(.x, na.rm=T)/sqrt(sum(!is.na(.x))), .names="se_{col}")) %>% head()
```

Which results in

```
   gear   mpg   cyl se_mpg se_cyl
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     3  16.1  7.47     NA     NA
2     4  24.5  4.67     NA     NA
3     5  21.4  6        NA     NA
```

However, if I switch the order of the individual `across` commands, I get the following:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(gear) %>% select(mpg,cyl) %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), ~sd(.x, na.rm=T)/sqrt(sum(!is.na(.x))), .names="se_{col}"),
            across(everything(), ~mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE), .names = "{col}")) %>% head()

# A tibble: 3 x 5
   gear se_mpg se_cyl   mpg   cyl
  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     3  0.871  0.307  16.1  7.47
2     4  1.52   0.284  24.5  4.67
3     5  2.98   0.894  21.4  6
```

Why is this the case? Does it have something to do with my usage of `everything()`? In my situation I'd like the `mean` and the `standard error of the mean` calculated across every variable in my dataset.

Comment: Can you please make a complete example? Why does your code start with `summarize` ? Where is the dataframe/

Comment: Oh wow I did not realize the code was incomplete. Fixed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why `summarize` behaves like that, it's probably due to an underlying interaction of the two `across` functions (although it seems weird to me). Anyway, I suggest you to write a single `across` statement and use a list of lambda functions as suggested by the `across` [documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html).

In this way it doesn't matter if the mean or the standard deviation is specified as first function, you will get no NAs.

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  select(mpg, cyl) %>% 
  summarize(across(everything(), list(
    mean = ~mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE),
    se = ~sd(.x, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(sum(!is.na(.x)))
  ), .names = "{fn}_{col}"))

# A tibble: 3 x 5
#    gear mean_mpg se_mpg mean_cyl se_cyl
#   <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1     3     16.1  0.871     7.47  0.307
# 2     4     24.5  1.52      4.67  0.284
# 3     5     21.4  2.98      6     0.894



mtcars %>% 
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  select(mpg, cyl) %>% 
  summarize(across(everything(), list(
    se = ~sd(.x, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(sum(!is.na(.x))),
    mean = ~mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)
  ), .names = "{fn}_{col}"))

# A tibble: 3 x 5
#    gear se_mpg mean_mpg se_cyl mean_cyl
#  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1     3  0.871     16.1  0.307     7.47
# 2     4  1.52      24.5  0.284     4.67
# 3     5  2.98      21.4  0.894     6
```

Comment: Thanks. It's odd that it's happening, since the operations should be happening simultaneously.

Comment: I agree with you. I didn't manage to understand the issue, only to find a workaround